# Objective c Git API wrappers?

Tags: objective-c, git

Is there an Objective-C based git wrapper to connect to and download from repositories, checkin etc?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Git.framework](https://github.com/geoffgarside/Git.framework) might work for what you want.

Comment: Doh! all seems a bit obvious now :-)